# How to pass a scriptlet variable into onclick() function call to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to read a variable and then have to pass that as an argument to a function after onclick().
I am using JSP, so I am reading the variable using scriptlets

```
<% int lateRegDays = 6;%>
```

I am passing the variable as

```
onclick="displayDatePicker('startTestAdminNo','mdy',<%=lateRegdays %>,120,0,3);"
```

But, I am unable to pass the valueof 6. The string "<%=lateRegDays%>" is being passed to the function. However, when I tried to print the value using alert, it worked. The changes I did is,

```
onclick='<%="alert("+lateRegDays+")"%>'
```

In the similar fashion, I need to know, how to pass all my arguments to function with this scriptlet variable. The entire code snippet is:

```
<td><input name="startTestAdminNo"></td>
  <td>
        <chtml:img srcKey="order.calendar.search" onclick="displayDatePicker('startTestAdminNo','mdy',<%=lateRegdays %>,120,0,3);"
            altKey="order.calendar.alt_search" bundle="prompt" />
  </td>
```

I need help with this as I am stuckand I don't know how to pass multiple arguments along with a scriptlet variable

Answer (score 2):

`Scriplets` will generate the HTML content when the Browser loads the JSP page, so if you want to use it inside your javascript, you need to capture that `lateRegDays` variable during the page loading time as below:

```
<script>
var lateRegDays; <!-- global variable -->
function init() {
lateRegDays = '<%= lateRegDays %>';
}
function  displayDatePicker(...) {
  // Get the lateRegDays var
}
</script>
<body onload="init()">
<!-- your code -->
</body>
```

P.S.: `Scriplets` are legacy code (invented in early 2000 by Sun), which is not a best practice to use them, so avoid them by using the latest front-end technology stack for the presentation layer.